# Div to overflow horizontally (to the right)

Tags: css

I have a div, with a few input boxes in a div and my div has a fixed height. I would like for this to overflow to the right instead of the bottom.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u0s86tzz/1/)

```
<div>
<input type="text"/><br>
<input type="text"/><br>
<input type="text"/><br>
<input type="text"/><br>
<input type="text"/><br>
<input type="text"/><br>
<input type="text"/><br>
<input type="text"/><br>
<input type="text"/><br>
<input type="text"/><br>
<input type="text"/><br>
<input type="text"/><br>
<input type="text"/><br>
```

```
div {
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
}
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with removing the `<br>`s?

Comment: I added <br/> because, these items are dynamically generated and are within a div which has a fixed height. I want the div to overflow to the right.

Comment: Can’t the generator simply _not_ generate those `<br>`s? There’s really no reason for the line breaks to be there if you want to align the text fields horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` for the content elements you want to be horizontally scrolled, and add `white-space:nowrap;` to the container.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/4Lex5wdo/

```css
#container {
    width:500px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.contents {
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:20px;
}

#one {
    background-color:#ABC;
    overflow-y: auto;
    white-space: normal;
}
#two {
    background-color:#333;
}
#three {
    background-color:#888;
}
#four {
    background-color:#E29E1E;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="contents" id="one">
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  text text text
    </div>
    <div class="contents" id="two"></div>
    <div class="contents" id="three"></div>
    <div class="contents" id="four"></div>
</div>
```

---

### Update

If you want the divs inside the container to be scrollable just add `overflow-y: auto; white-space: normal;` to the elements you want, for example if you want just the first div `#one` to be scrollable as you mentioned on your comment, do this:

```
#one {
    background-color:#ABC;
    overflow-y: auto;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

if you want all of the divs inside of it to be scrollable give this properties to the class that they all have instead which is `.contents`:

```
.contents {
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:20px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

You can check the live example [here on Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Lex5wdo/2/) or run the code snippet, it's already updated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I want to be able to overflow the contents of the first div, assuming #one has a fixed height. More like columns without having to use col-count.

Comment: Then just give `overflow-y: auto; white-space: normal;` to `#one` check out my update or jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4Lex5wdo/2/

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to do this, you have to get rid of the breaklines (`<br>`), and you have to add `overflow-x:scroll;` to your css code for the div.

You need to also set the inputs to have a `display:inline-block;` property.

If you want to keep the breaklines, the only way the div will overflow is if the div has less of a width than the components within it (in this case: the input fields).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u0s86tzz/7/)